# Android Beacon Library - Manually starting background scan

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

This is a question regarding [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/documentation.html).

---

Because of Android 8 (Oreo)'s restriction on background service, the author of the library has changed the mechanism of starting background service in Android 8.

As far as I can observe, the background service needs a much longer time to start than Android 7 or below, **even if the app is already started**.

What I want to do is to reduce this time as much as possible.
One of the way is to force launch the background scanning if the app is opened by the user.
For instance, I want to do something like

`BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).startbackgroundScanningIfNotRunning();`

In `onCreate()` of MainActivity.

But I think there is no such API. Is there anyway to do this?

Or, is it possible for the library to handle itself (through an app update)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to do something like described in the question, it may not be useful.  The problem is that Android 8 prevents apps from running in the background long-term.  In order to manually start a scan in the background, your app must be running in the first place.  If Android 8 has disallowed this, then you aren't going to be able to do it, anyway.

For an explanation of how Android 8 blocks apps from running in the background and how the library works around this, you can read this blog post if you have not already: 
 http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8

If you have **somehow** managed to get your app running long-term in the background (e.g. by using a foreground service), you can always kick off a scan manually by starting beacon ranging/monitoring in foreground mode (from the library perspective), which will schedule an immediate ScanJob that will keep running and start itself over and over.  To make sure you are in foreground mode, you simply need to refrain from using the `BackgroundPowerSaver` and don't make any calls to `beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(...)` to true.

Comment: I understand the limitations from Android 8; but as far as I know, those limitations do not apply when the app is already opened. But I observed that even if the app is opened, the scan isn't running. Given that the app is already in the foreground, I still want to start the background scanning function provided by the library. Or I cannot use the `Bootstrap` class in this situation?

Comment: I must be missing something... If the user opens the app, then it is in the foreground.  Of course you can scan then.  The library will immediately trigger an immediate scan when the BeaconManager background flag changes to false (either manually or with BackgroundPowerSaver).  If it is not doing this, then something is wrong with the app setup.

Comment: I didn't use `BackgroundPowerSaver` yet, I planned to add it at the last stage to reduce variables before I successfully implemented everything. After adding it, looks like I cannot reproduce the problem anymore. Thanks!

Comment: suggest you update the document about this as well, since generally users think a `BackgroundPowerSaver` does not affect any functionality, but it does. For example you may mention this specifically in a section about Oreo. By the way, I also wonder why you made `BackgroundPowerSaver` an optional choice for users, but it looks like (At least I can't find from docs) it does not have any drawbacks?

Comment: I guess the key point is that if you do not use BackgroundPowerSaver with Android 8, then you must manually notify the BeaconManager when the app comes back to the foreground, otherwise the next scan will remain limited to the background 15 minute cycle imposed by the operating system.  I agree this must be communicated, but it is a hard concept for beginners to grasp.